# data in multiple columns in one single column or row

Tags: r

I would like my data in one single column or row. Any suggestions

```r
library(purrr)
1:2 %>% map(~ sample(1:10, 5, replace = T))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 8 1 5 8 4
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  5  4  8 10 10
```

Desired output:
`8 1 5 8 4 5  4  8 10 10` or

```
8 
1 
5 
8 
4 
5  
4  
8 
10 
10
```

Comment: `sample(1:10, 5*2, replace = T)` ？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `unlist` the output from `map`.

```
unlist(1:2 %>% purrr::map(~ sample(1:10, 5, replace = T)))
```

However, I think this is more of a `replicate` job.

```
c(replicate(2, sample(1:10, 5, replace = T)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rerun`

```
library(purrr)
2 %>%
  rerun(sample(1:10, 5, replace = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sapply` + `c` like below

```
c(sapply(1:2, function(k) sample(10, 5, replace = TRUE)))
```